# Getting scope from LinkedIn access token

Tags: linkedin-api

Basically, I want to check if access token (that my user has), has w_share in its scope. Is it possible?

```
let url = consumer.getAuthorizeUrl({
    redirect_uri: '/callback',
    scope: 'r_basicprofile w_share',
    response_type: 'code'
  });
```

That is how I basically authorise users. Any help?

I need functionality similar to facebook's debug token.